# How to return to "View Parent" from ASWebAutheticationSession

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, oauth, aswebauthenticationsession

How to return from the ASWebAutheticationSession completion handler back to the View?

Edit: Just for clearance this is not the original code in my project this is extremely shortened and is just for showcasing what I mean.

Here's an example of a code

```swift
struct SignInView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var signedIn: UIState
    
    var body: some View {
        let AuthenticationSession = AuthSession()
        AuthenticationSession.webAuthSession.presentationContextProvider = AuthenticationSession
        AuthenticationSession.webAuthSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
        AuthenticationSession.webAuthSession.start()
    }
}

class AuthSession: NSObject, ObservableObject, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    var webAuthSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession.init(
        url: AuthHandler.shared.signInURL()!,
        callbackURLScheme: "",
        completionHandler: { (callbackURL: URL?, error: Error?) in
            
            // check if any errors appeared
            
            // get code from authentication

            // Return to view to move on with code? (return code)
        })

    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {

        return ASPresentationAnchor()
    }

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is call the sign In process and then get back to the view with the code from the authentication to move on with it.

Could somebody tell me how this may be possible?
Thanks.

Comment: looking at your code, I think you really need to read the basics of Swift at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html  
 and also need to understand the basics of SwiftUI, see the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/.
 For managing your model data, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: This code is not the original code that is inside of my project this is just an example and extremely shortened for visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm correctly understanding your question but it is normally done with publishers, commonly with the @Published wrapper, an example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.viewModel.signIn(user: "example", password: "example")
            }
            label: {
                Text("Sign in")
            }
            
            if self.viewModel.signedIn {
                Text("Successfully logged in")
            }
            else if let error = self.viewModel.signingError {
                Text("Error while logging in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var signingStatus = SigningStatus.idle
    
    var signedIn: Bool {
        if case .success = self.signingStatus { return true }
        
        return false
    }
    
    var signingError: Error? {
        if case .failure(let error) = self.signingStatus { return error }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    func signIn(user: String, password: String) {
        self.dummyAsyncProcessWithCompletionHandler { [weak self] success in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            guard success else {
                self.updateSigning(.failure(CustomError(errorDescription: "Login failed")))
                return
            }
            
            self.updateSigning(.success)
        }
    }
    
    private func updateSigning(_ status: SigningStatus) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.signingStatus = status
        }
    }
    
    private func dummyAsyncProcessWithCompletionHandler(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        Task {
            print("Signing in")

            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 500_000_000)
            
            guard Int.random(in: 0..<9) % 2 == 0 else {
                print("Error")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
            print("Success")
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
    enum SigningStatus {
        case idle
        case success
        case failure(Error)
    }
    
    struct CustomError: Error, LocalizedError {
        var errorDescription: String?
    }
}
```